# Returning XmlDocument from an XmlElement

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I'm not sure if all the details are here.

Initially, I was supposed to send a SOAP request and read its response into a dataset.

The following code worked:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
cred.CredExecution mycredit = new cred.CredExecution();
ds = mycredit.RetrieveParsedRawData(inquiry, true);
// I have the Web Reference "cred" added to the project.
// Since I wasn't sure if a service reference was needed, I added that too.
```

Now the response format has changed to XML, and I'm not sure how to read it.

I changed the code as follows:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument XmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
cred.CredExecution mycredit = new cred.CredExecution();
XmlDoc = mycredit.RetrieveParsedRawData(inquiry, true);
```

But it fails with the error:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'*

I tried using:

```
System.Xml.XmlElement XmlEle = new System.Xml.XmlElement();
```

but the system fails saying it is protected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of it, RetrieveParsedRawData returns an XmlElement instead of an xmldocument.
so this should work.

```
cred.CredExecution mycredit = new cred.CredExecution();
System.Xml.XmlElement XmlEle = mycredit.RetrieveParsedRawData(inquiry, true);
System.Xml.XmlDocument XmlDoc = XmlEle.OwnerDocument;
```

Comment: When I updated the code like you suggested, it complied without errors. Now how to see the response?  When it was a dataset, I used "ds.WriteXml(filePath);" to write the XML to a file. with XDoc, I'm not seeing any options for WriteXML. so I added "MessageBox.Show(XmlDoc.ToString());" and this displays "System.Xml.XmlDocument". From a different tool, I see the response for the same request as <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
...
...
      </RetrieveParsedRawDataResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Comment: To get the xml content you will have to call InnerText or InnerXml on the XmlElement.
you can find the documention on XmlElement here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innerxml.aspx

Comment: `XmlElement.OwnerDocument` is returning an instance of an `XmlDocument` but it's `InnerXml` property is empty.  Do I need to append the `XmlElement` to its own document?